# Detect Email id and add hyper link

Tags: javascript

I have a html code, It is generating from back end, i can use only the html page. I have no control to the back end code. I want add hyper link to all email address using **JavaScript**. Here is the html, I have only 3 rows of this, it can be many.

```
<div class="content">
    Title: dev<br>
    Phone: 1234567890<br>
    Email: test@test.com<br>
</div>
<div class="content">
    Title: dev<br>
    Phone: 1234567890<br>
    Email: test@test.com<br>
</div>
<div class="content">
    Title: dev<br>
    Phone: 1234567890<br>
    Email: test@test.com<br>
</div>
```

Comment: Your question is unclear, can you give an example

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Do your research. [Search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO. Attempt to do the work. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck.

Comment: I want to just add hyperlink to the all email address using javaScript, I can't edit the html code. Please show me how can I detect email address and add hyperlink on it using javaScript.

Answer (score 0):

This is simple...

Use regular expression to match emails form text and replace them with hyper links..

```js
var text =  document.querySelectorAll('div.content');
   
 //use your reg here...
var emailReg = /(([^<>()\[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@(([^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+\.)+[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]{2,})$/igmu ;

text.forEach(function(item){
  var textInner = item.innerHTML;

  var email = textInner.match(emailReg)[0];

  var emailHype = `<a href="mailto:${email}">${email}</a>`;

  var textInner = textInner.replace(emailReg ,emailHype);
  item.innerHTML = textInner;
  
});
```

```html
<div class="content">abc@gmail.com</div>
<div class="content">
    Title: dev<br>
    Phone: 1234567890<br>
    Email: test@test.com<br>
</div>
<div class="content">
    Title: dev<br>
    Phone: 1234567890<br>
    Email: test@test.com<br>
</div>
```